# Is myiVar = nil supported in ARC?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I'm using a code snippet like

```
if ([Array count] != 0) {
    Array = nil;
}
Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Is this allowed when using ARC? Does this cause any kind of crashes? Why I'm doing this is each time when my method gets called `Array` gets a new set of data. I'm using this kind of snippet in many places of my class.

Comment: A brief suggestion to your coding style (and sorry for the nitpicking). There seems to be an agreement in the ObjC developer community that variable names start with a lowercase letter and class names start with an uppercase letter. Using uppercase first letters in variable names makes it harder for other developers to read your code.

Comment: You don't even need to set the array to nil before assigning it to a new NSMutableArray. When a variable is assigned, it's old value is released before it gets its new value.

Answer (score 10):

ARC aside, the operation is pointless. You assign an ivar to `nil` then immediately assign to something else. This is no different from just assigning it to the something else.

Before ARC this would have given you a memory leak (with or without your assignment to `nil`) if there variable had a previous value. With ARC there is no leak.

Comment: Not so sure about the leak. If the Array was not retained why should it leak?

Comment: I'm assuming the section of code above would be called multiple times - so if there was a value in `Array` it would have been created via alloc/init

Comment: @Alin: The `-init:` call gives a +1 to the retain count.

Comment: I was not assuming that the code is called multiple times. So if you  had NSMutable *Array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:4]; getting the method called you'll not get a leak for the first time :)

Answer (score 3):

Best solution : test and see by yourself ! This is a really short example !

But yes, this works of course !
ARC means Automatic Reference Counting. It just says you don't have to care about `release`, `retain` and so on.

If you want an object to be nil, you still can, as it is a simple pointer assignment !

And about your code, you set Array to nil before re-assigning it oO !

Try to get the logic of your code :

> If my Array has objects
>
> ```
> Then Array point to a new nil object
> ```

But in all case you do:

> My Array point to a new NSMutableArray object

So whether or not your condition is evaluated to true, your code is useless as the variable will take another value just after !

Comment: This is much more cheerful than my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The sample code you showed is valid. Here are a few variations:

```
if ([Array count] != 0) {
    Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Example 2:

```
if ([Array count] != 0) {
    Array = [NSMutableArray array]; //value will be retained
}
```

Example 3:

```
if ([Array count] != 0) {
    self.Array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //Will NOT leak under ARC.
}
```

Example 4:

```
//if ([Array count] != 0) {
[Array removeAllObjects];
//}
```

All four examples are valid under ARC.

Another thing: instance variables typically have their first letter lowercase, while still following the CamelCase method. Another way to do it is to have an underscore before the name of the variable: this is done if you don't have a `@synthesize` method to match your `@property` value.